# How to replace the root tag with the actual message type name?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to get your opinion with regards to XSLT code which i can use to replace my root tag with the actual name of the message (ns1).

The 'Rechnungen' should be replaced by the actual message type name, with extra header. Thank you!

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV xmlns:ns2="http://test.com">
  <Rechnungen>
    <Kopf>
      <K_Belegdatum>Belegdatum</K_Belegdatum>
      <K_Leistungsdatum>Leistungsdatum</K_Leistungsdatum>
      <K_VBelN>Faktura</K_VBelN>
    </Kopf>
    <Positionen>
      <P_Belegdatum>12092018</P_Belegdatum>
      <P_Leistungsdatum>22072018</P_Leistungsdatum>
      <P_VBelN>12345</P_VBelN>
    </Positionen>
  </Rechnungen>
  <Rechnungen>
    <Kopf>
      <K_Belegdatum>Belegdatum</K_Belegdatum>
      <K_Leistungsdatum>Leistungsdatum</K_Leistungsdatum>
      <K_VBelN>Faktura</K_VBelN>
    </Kopf>
    <Positionen>
      <P_Belegdatum>12092018</P_Belegdatum>
      <P_Leistungsdatum>29072018</P_Leistungsdatum>
      <P_VBelN>67890</P_VBelN>
    </Positionen>
  </Rechnungen>
</ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV>
```

Desired Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
  <ns0:Message1>
    <ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV xmlns:ns2="http://test.com">
      <Kopf>
        <K_Belegdatum>Belegdatum</K_Belegdatum>
        <K_Leistungsdatum>Leistungsdatum</K_Leistungsdatum>
        <K_VBelN>Faktura</K_VBelN>
      </Kopf>
      <Positionen>
        <P_Belegdatum>12092018</P_Belegdatum>
        <P_Leistungsdatum>22072018</P_Leistungsdatum>
        <P_VBelN>12345</P_VBelN>
      </Positionen>
    </ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV>
    <ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV xmlns:ns2="http://test.com">
      <Kopf>
        <K_Belegdatum>Belegdatum</K_Belegdatum>
        <K_Leistungsdatum>Leistungsdatum</K_Leistungsdatum>
        <K_VBelN>Faktura</K_VBelN>
      </Kopf>
      <Positionen>
        <P_Belegdatum>12092018</P_Belegdatum>
        <P_Leistungsdatum>29072018</P_Leistungsdatum>
        <P_VBelN>67890</P_VBelN>
      </Positionen>
    </ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV>
  </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Comment: Have you missed a bit from your XML? Your desired output is showing that the `Rechnungen` has been removed, rather than being replaced by anything (and there is no sign of "ns1" anywhere either). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the identity template, as this will handle copying all the existing nodes unchanged.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You then want a template to skip over `ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV` so that it is not copied in its original position

```
<xsl:template match="ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Instead, you then want a template that matching `Rechnungen` where you can replace it with a copy of its parent element

```
<xsl:template match="Rechnungen">
  <xsl:element name="{../name()}" namespace="{../namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://test.com"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Rechnungen">
    <xsl:element name="{../name()}" namespace="{../namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you are using XSLT 3.0, then you can tidy up the code slightly, and do this instead....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://test.com"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="ns2:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Rechnungen">
    <xsl:variable name="currentChildren" select="node()" />
    <xsl:copy select="..">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentChildren" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note, I wasn't sure if `ns0:Messages` was in your input XML or not, or if you wanted to added it. If if does need to be added, just add this template to either of the above XSLTs:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ns0:Message1>
  </ns0:Messages>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your quick help, Tim. I've run the code and the output is almost ok. I ran the code and the output i've got is a bit different. The parent element (with ns1) should occur multiple times, same as the number of Rechnungen occurrence.  

The output i've got contains multiple </ns1:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV>, which is under the parent <ns1:CU_DE_Fitnesfirst_INVOIC_CSV xmlns:ns1="http://lekkerland.com/B2B/CU/Fitnesfirst/IF5041">. Kindly advise..

Comment: It sounds like your actual XML is different to what you have shown in the question. Using the XML in your question does achieve the desired results (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpN ), so you might need to edit your question to show more accurate XML. Thanks!

Comment: It may be just a case that you have to change the namespace declaration in the XSLT.

Comment: sorry, Tim. my fault.. still refreshing my skill at xslt :) The code you've provided is working perfectly.. thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry. The output XML, after the XSLT code is ok. However, the header seems to contain the namespace. Appreciate your inputs on this.

Expected:
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">

Output: 
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns2="http://test.com" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">

Comment: It shouldn't really cause a problem as to where the namespace is declared. Although you could try using `exclude-result-prefixes` perhaps. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpN/1